# Does editing service config recreate the service object?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have a service type Loadbalancer in GKE and I want to add "externalTrafficPolicy: Local" to it, and I'm wondering whether this will cause it to be recreated and thus loose the current external IP address or it will keep that address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not recreate the service, and you can [Reserve static IP Address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address) in the service just to be safe.

loadBalancerIP enables you to choose a specific IP address for the load balancer. The IP address must not be in use by another internal TCP/UDP load balancer or Service. If omitted, an ephemeral IP is assigned.

You can refer to below docs for more info, how-to and details.

[Reserving a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)

[GKE Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/service-parameters#lb_ip)